# Using a variable that may be null in a where statement

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

I select a value into a mysql variable. Eg...

```
select          @userId := userId
from            myTable 
where           id = ?;
```

The value of @userId can be null.

Now I want to update the rows in another table based on the value of @userId.

Simply stating "where userId = @userId" will not always work, since "userId = null" will never come back true in mysql, even if userId is null.

The following statement appears to work fine instead...

```
update          myOtherTable
set             something = "something"
where           (
                    userId = @userId or 
                    (@userId is null and userId is null)
                );
```

...however I just wanted to run this by the gurus here, to make sure it is mostly "okay".  (Evaluating a variable apart from a column in the where statement feels a bit strange to me.)

Thoughts?

Comment: You can use the `<=>` [operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) for null-safe equality

Comment: awseome.  thnx I learned something new.

Comment: Have you considered using a subselect instead of storing the intermediate query result in a variable?

Comment: See if the `<=>` operator gives you what you need.